Alexa Widget - test DataStore Update
I am currently trying to develop an alexa widget for visual echo devices which is supposed to display data from a DataStore.
I could bind the DataStore data to the
widget i
n the APL code and install it on my echo show. I can also send updated data using the "Update data store" button in the widget authoring tool. The widget on the echo show then shows the updated data as expected.
However when I try to update the datastore in the lamda handler function for Alexa.DataStore.PackageManager.UsagesInstalled, I receive the following error when calling the https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/datastore/commands endpoint:
{
    "results": [
        {
            "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AMATJ3...",
            "type": "INVALID_DEVICE",
            "message": "The device does not have any package from this skill"
        }
    ]
}

I implemented the handler according to the examples in the official documentation. The device ID is retrieved from the UsagesInstalled envelope when I install the widget via the widget authoring tool, so it should be correct...I also tried to set the target to "user", so all my devices get updated, but I get the same response...So I wonder, do I need to publish my skill to make this work? I cannot find anything regarding this in the official documentation. Can I test updating the datastore from the lambda function without publishing the skill?

Enable APL and data store packages
Implement Widget with data binding to a datastore
Implement lambda function handler for Alexa.DataStore.PackageManager.UsagesInstalled
Update data store in said lambda function
Deploy and build evertything
Install the widget via the widget authoring tool => data is not displayed
Check logs to find above mentioned error
Update data via the "Update data store" button => data is displayed successfully


Are you testing on a physical Alexa device ?  As the Amazon documentation for the authoring tool states that you must install the widget on a device to test the data store.

Yes, I test it by using the "Send to Device" (Install, not preview) button in the authoring tool...That's when I get the mentioned error in the logs...or is there another way to install the widget without publishing it?
